# Is watching people cook haraam foods haraam? (eg. pork belly, pure vanilla ice cream etc)

Tags: food

I've watched many cooking videos on youtube and I normally see a lot of people cook things that are haraam. For example, pork belly, beef wellington (contains bacon), vanilla ice cream (vanilla extract), and other things that if I were to eat it would be haraam.

I always wondered if watching those videos would be haraam. I have no intention of making the foods either, I am just watching the videos themselves.

I don't know very much about the ayat and sunnah so I can't find out if it is haraam or not. Can someone please help me find an answer? Jazakallah, Assalamualaikum my dear brothers and sisters.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any intention to cook your eat then it is not a sin. But why would you watch those videos that
are just wasting your time and doesn't benefit you? I think you got your answer.
Jazakallah Khair